# Oozie simple ssh job failing : AUTH_FAILED: Not able to perform operation

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying simple ssh job using Cloudera oozie.

**job.properties**:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/ssh
```

**workflow.xml**:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="ssh-wf">
    <start to="ssh"/>

    <action name="ssh">
        <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
            <host>localhost</host>
            <command>date</command>
        </ssh>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>SSH action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

When tried to run job using following command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/ssh/job.properties -run
```

The job gets SUSPENDED with following error:

```
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: AUTH_FAILED: Not able to perform operation [ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o KbdInteractiveDevices=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=20 cloudera@localhost  mkdir -p oozie-oozi/0000003-170304124323783-oozie-oozi-W/ssh--ssh/ ] | ErrorStream: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

What is the possible issue? The passwordless login in enabled for localhost.

Comment: Passwordless login is enabled for which user? `oozie` or `cloudera`?

Comment: for user cloudera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie server will run the SSH as `oozie` user to run the ssh as. The targeted user at the remote will be as per the config i.e., `cloudera`.

Enable password-less login for `oozie` user. Create SSH keys for `oozie` user and copy its public key to the `authorized_keys` of `cloudera` user.